# Indicating which version of a crate generated docs are for

Tags: rust, rustdoc

When you generate documentation for a Rust crate with Cargo and rustdoc, I don't see any indication in the generated pages which version of the crate it's for. For example, take a look at [the log crate's documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/index.html). Is there a way to know which version of the crate a set of docs are for?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a straight forward way to do this, but there is [an issue about it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24336). You may be able to hack something that uses the "extra html" feature of rustdoc though.